# How is the account state updated on HD wallet transactions where the address are different everytime

Tags: go-ethereum, addresses, accounts, merkle-patricia-tries, hd-wallets

I am implementing an HD wallet in ethereum (BIP-39 and BIP-44), so let's say I generated an account ***A*** with a private key ***PrK*** and public key ***PlK***. From them I derive many keys and hence addresses ***Addrs-1...n*** that I give to my clients so that they can send me transactions.

When a client sends me a transaction to a derived address ***Addrs-8***, lets say, How does an ethereum node recognise that this one was derived from ***PrK*** and hence belongs to Account ***A*** (and updates the balance of it). I know that wallet software deal with these by deriving the whole tree for key ***PrK*** as explained in [Account Discovery section of BIP-44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#account-discovery), but given that nodes need also to reflect the status of individual accounts, I wonder how they identify derivations?

Comment: For go-ethereum client different address are completely unrelated.

Comment: So this means that in order to spend the funds received in Addrs-8 I need to sign the spending transaction with Addrs-8 primary key instead of with PrK ?

Comment: Yes, Ethereum uses an account model to track balances where each account is independent.